# Validate custom xprofile field on edit profile page in BuddyPress

Tags: validation, email, field, buddypress

OK so I’m struggling with this one for hours now and can’t get it to work, but it feels like there is a strait forward simple and elegant solution. All I want to do is to validate the value of a custom xprofile email field when a member is editing its info. Trying to mimic how xprofile_screen_edit_profile() works with returning error before saving, I tried to add_action/add_filter/do_action/apply_filter to xprofile_updated_profile, xprofile_screen_edit_profile, bp_actions, bp_screens, xprofile_data_value_before_save and more, but I failed every time probably because I don’t know how to properly use them. All I want to do is simple as:

```
 function my_validate_email () {
    if (!empty($field_id->value) && !is_email($field_id->value))
bp_core_add_message( __( 'That email address is invalid. Check the formatting and try again.', 'buddypress' ), 'error' );
//and redirect back to editing, same like for the required fields
}
add_action( 'bp_hook_here', 'my_validate_email' );
```

Please help with the correct way of doing this, possibly without using additional plugin
Thanks so much

Answer (score 1):

Is this an additional email field ? 
And not the user's email related to registration?
If it is not an additional email field, then use WP hooks. 
If it is, take a look at bp-xprofile-classes, function save(), ~Line 1032

And do something like this (untested):

```
function my_validate_email ($this ) {
  // figure out if $this is an array or object and adjust accordingly...

 if ( $this['field_id'] == $the_id_of_your_email_field ) { 
    if (!empty($this['value']) && !is_email($this['value'])) {
       $this['field_id'] = 0;
       bp_core_add_message( __( 'That email address is invalid. Check the formatting and try again.', 'buddypress' ), 'error' );
    }
  }

  return $this;

}
add_action( 'xprofile_data_before_save', 'my_validate_email', 1, 1 );
```

Comment: Yes this is an additional custom email field that is not related to the user's registration one. I tried your function but var_dump($this) doesn't return anything with this hook.

Comment: @shanebp post a not working solution. And this user post more not making sense code. And then if you ask the user for improvement the user close the post or keep silence. This user is a scam!!